# Restoring a pre-trained model

Tags: tensorflow, restore

I am restoring a pre-trained model in TensorFlow and would like to know if my code works as desired. Here is the code below. It looks like it does not make use of the pre-trained model because the loss from the code below is way higher than training error, e.g., 200 something. Please let me know how I can modify it. Thank you in advance.

```
def main(_):

    with tf.Graph().as_default() as g:

        x, img, rows, cols = load_image(FLAGS.input, FLAGS.image_size)

        with slim.arg_scope(resnet_v2.resnet_arg_scope(weight_decay=0.0005)):
            logits, endpoints = resnet_v2.resnet_v2_152(x, nb_classes, is_training=False)

        predictions = tf.argmax(logits, 1)

        saver = tf.train.Saver()

    with tf.Session(graph=g) as sess:

        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        # Load a pretrained model.
        print("\nLoading a model...")
        saver.restore(sess, checkpoint_path)

        print("\nFeedforwarding...")
        pred, loss_out, output, grads_val = sess.run([predictions, loss, conv_layer, norm_grads])
```

Comment: Where is your feed dict in the code ?

Comment: I directly load images from load_image function and feed it into resnet_v2_152. I followed tensorflow slim [train_image_classifier.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/slim/train_image_classifier.py) and modified it.